# Why does my code make me type "yes" or "no" twice to get the result I want instead of just once?

Tags: python

Why does this code make me type yes or no twice to get the result I want instead of just once?

This is for the python dice roll text game, btw...

```
import random
min = 1
max = 20

# <!--TWO D-20's, A-LA DUNGEONS AND DRAGAONS--!>

roll_again = "yes"

while roll_again == "yes" or roll_again == "y":
    print("Rolling the dice")
    print("The values are --- ")
    print(random.randint(min, max))
    print(random.randint(min, max))
    roll_again = input("Would you like to play again?")
    answer = input()
if answer == ('yes'):print("OK, here we go!")
elif answer == ("no"):print("Sorry about that, please try again another time.")
```

I am entering into a python class on Monday, this is one of the more common types of beginners code (granted I spiced it up by changing the dice from 6 sided to 20 sided, but it's more fun that way...lol) that I have read in some of the python books and sites I have visited, so I wanted to kind of get my feet wet a bit before I start my class.

So, any idea why I have to type yes or no twice, hitting enter after each time, to get it to run properly?

For the record, I am on Win10 right now but I also mostly use Parrot Security OS (Linux)...

Thanks for any and all feedback which anyone can provide...I know it's probably a stupid noob mistake or oversight, since I don't really know or understand the basics, but the quicker I can grasp them the better...

Comment: `input` is a prompt. You've written it twice, so you get two prompts. `roll_again` stores their answer. You're using `input("Would you like to play again?")` as a `print` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's function `input()` asks for users to input and waits the answer. As it can be seen in your code, you're doing it two times:

```
roll_again = input("Would you like to play again?")
answer = input()
```

The variable `roll_again` is being redeclarated to the first user's input, then the variable `answer` is getting the second user's input. You maybe meant to do something like:

```
roll_again = input("Would you like to play again?")
answer = roll_again
```

But first of all, there is no need to create an `answer` variable, you could simply use the `roll_again` on the `if`. Also the `if` statement is out of the `while` so your code might not work as you're trying to anyways~ (it will re-roll if user inputs `yes` but it will not print the message you're trying to; that will only happen when the user inputs `no` as that will go out of the while and *blah blah blah*)

This should be alright:

```
import random
min = 1
max = 20

# <!--TWO D-20's, A-LA DUNGEONS AND DRAGAONS--!>

roll_again = "yes"

while roll_again == "yes" or roll_again == "y":
    print("Rolling the dice")
    print("The values are --- ")
    print(random.randint(min, max))
    print(random.randint(min, max))
    
    roll_again = input("Would you like to play again?")
    if roll_again == 'yes' or roll_again == 'y': print("OK, here we go!")
    else: print("Sorry about that, please try again another time.")
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you for explaining that! 

I did not realize how different it is from HTML, VC++, VB, etc...the explanation helped tons!

Answer (score 1):

Every time you call the `input()` function, it prompts for input. Since you call it twice for each iteration of your `while` loop, the user is prompted twice per iteration. You should instead only call the `input()` function once in your `while` loop.

You can also avoid using the `answer` variable if you just use the `roll_again` variable for your conditions for your `if` and `elif`.

Comment: thank you for your answer also, as I had mentioned above, this language is much different than HTML, VC++, VB, etc...basically the 3 main languages that I had learned previously...also figured out last night while messing with this that spaces / tabbing really matters here! So strange...Visual C++ Visual Basic and HTML -- none of those worry about where you put your space or tab, from what I remember...we just make it pretty so we can read it easier, not because the language dictates so...this is an odd language to get the hang of....